# Cannot open a React app in the browser after dockerising

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to dockerise a react app. I'm using the following Dockerfile to achieve this.

```html
# base image
FROM node:9.4

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Specify port
EXPOSE 8081

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Also, in my package.json the start script is defined as
 `"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    ....
  }`

I build the image as:

```
docker build . -t myimage
```

And I finally run the image, as

```
docker run IMAGE_ID
```

This command then runs the image, however when I go to localhost:8080 or localhost:8081 I dont see anything.

However, when I go into the docker container for myimage, and do `curl -X GET http:localhost:8080` I'm able to access my react app.

I also deployed this on google-kubernetes and exposed a load-balancer service on this. However, the same thing happened, I cannot access the react-app on the exposed endpoint, but when I logged into the container, and made curl request, I was getting back the index.html.

So, how do I run the image of this docker image so that I could access the application through a browser.

Comment: when doing this locally you have to publish ports using `-p` option when running the containers so you can access the container through published port.

Comment: It's really bad practice to use the dev server for a docker image IMO.  Too easy to promote it through production.  You'll also get worse performance and weird development issues.  You should instead do an `npm run build` to build the project, then copy the build files into Docker, and serve that index.html with node.

Comment: @JakeLuby could you elaborate on how to copy the build files (the dist folder) generated from running `npm run build`?

Comment: Using the COPY method like you're already doing.  Your command would then change to be `node /path/to/dist/bin/www` (or something like that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use EXPOSE in Dockerfile it simply states that the service is listening on the specified port (in your case 8081), but it does not actually create any port forwarding.

To actually forward traffic from host machine to the service you must use the `-p` flag to specify port mapping

For example:
`docker run -d -p 80:8080 myimage` would start a container and forward requests to localhost:80 to the containers port 8080

More about EXPOSE here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

---

**UPDATE**

So usually when you are developing node applications locally and run webpack dev-server it will listen on 127.0.0.1 which is fine since you intend to visit the site from the same machine as it is hosted. But since in docker the container can be thought of as a separate instance that means you need to be able to access it from the "outside" world which means that it is necessary to reconfigure the dev-server to listen on 0.0.0.0 (which basically means all IP addresses assigned to the "instance")

So by updating the dev-server config to listen on 0.0.0.0 you should be able to visit your application from your host machine. 
Link to documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost

Comment: Still not working with this method of running the image too

Comment: And I am a bit confused about the ports you mention - 8080 and 8081... What is your webpack devserver configuration? Is the application listening on port 8080?

Comment: I'm using `sudo docker run -p 80:8080 myimage` to run the container. And, my server is configured to listen on port 8080.

Comment: And what kind of http response are you getting? 4xx, 5xx? Can you try running `docker container ls -a` to get the container id and then `docker logs -f container_id` to see if there's any output there?

Comment: When I run the image, the following gets printed out to the console. `
> admin-xxxx-xx-front@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
⚠ ｢wds｣: Unable to open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do not use the --open flag
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
⚠ ｢wdm｣: Hash: ea2c9b3a5e6e52a356xx
Version: webpack 4.29.6
Time: 15600ms
Built at: 2019-06-25 18:45:10
......`

Comment: Aahhh... ok... can you change the localhost to 0.0.0.0 so that it is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080? And try removing the --open as well as it is not necessary there as well, right?

Comment: Here's how it can be done https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost

Comment: I build the image again and it still isnt working. :/ 
Its showing this as the [logs](https://imgur.com/a/BZsHdO9)

Comment: And you are visiting simply localhost in your browser? Without any ports specified?

Comment: No, I'm visiting port 8080 on localhost.

Comment: Well you should be just visiting `localhost` as your browser by default will look for port 80 and that's the one you have mapped to the containers 8080... 
So when you map the ports you are saying which localhost port you want to map to which container port. And since you said you use `sudo docker run -p 80:8080 myimage` that means you need to use port 80 on your host machine to visit service port 8080